# Invoke a web service without proxy using SOAP API in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have a web service with one exposed method GetData. It takes a string as input parameter and returns another string. I am able to invoke the web method using test tools with the below request.

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <GetData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <value>Enter my value</value>
    </GetData>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Can I get some help on how to invoke the same in a C# windows Application with out having a proxy reference and by using the end point details . (Ex:http://mymachine:1415/MyService.svc)

Comment: What are the reasons you don't want to use a proxy class? I think it's more robust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
     var result = wc.UploadString("http://localhost.:1415/MyService.svc", request);
}
```

**EDIT**

```
XNamespace s = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
XNamespace tempUri = "http://tempuri.org/";

var xDoc = new XDocument(
                    new XElement(
                        s + "Envelope",
                        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "s", s),
                        new XElement(
                            s + "Body",
                            new XElement(
                                tempUri+ "GetData",
                                new XElement(tempUri + "value","Enter my value")
                            )
                        )
                    )
                );

var request = xDoc.ToString();
```

Comment: would like to know how to create a SOAP request compatible to the above format